# Getting 200 code in Postman but 400 while automating the same request via rest assured

Tags: java, rest, api, automation, http-status-code-400

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr00x.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvmnh.png)

In post man, I am able to get 200 status code but when I am trying to automate it using rest assured, I am getting 400 error.

```
public class trial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        RestAssured.baseURI="https://api.planet.com";
        Response res=given().
        header("Authorization", "api-key ab2118c30721496495ddc8d4f3603d69").
        header("Content-Type", "application/json").
        queryParam("strict", "false").
        body("{" + 
                "  \"filter\": {  " + 
                "   \"type\":\"AndFilter\"," + 
                "   \"config\": [" + 
                "       {  " + 
                "         \"type\":\"RangeFilter\"," + 
                "         \"field_name\":\"cloud_cover\"," + 
                "         \"config\":{ " + 
                "            \"lte\":0.5" + 
                "         }" + 
                "       }" + 
                "  ]" + 
                "   " + 
                "}," + 
                "  \"item_types\": [\"PSScene3Band\"]," + 
                "  \"name\": \"Assignment\"" + 
                "}").
                when().
                post("/data/v1/searches/").
                then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON).
                extract().response();

        JsonPath js=ReusableMethods.rawToJson(res);
        System.out.println(res.getBody().asString());

    }

}
```

Comment: What additional messages or info do you get besides the 400 code?

Comment: Hi! Your request in postman contains 10 headers, however your code only have two (content-type and Authorization). I cannot see the content of the headers in your screenshot but maybe one of them is missing on your code?

Comment: @ronnyfm thats the error:   "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <400>.

 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80)'

Comment: @JaimeS, I added the header screenshot as well, those headers only populated after I sent the request with 2 headers.